# How can I use IndexOf in a List<object[]>?

Tags: c#, list

If I declare a List like,

```
List<object[]> People = new List<object[]>();
```

(in which `object[]` has two elements)

```
People.Add(new object[] {"Sam", 18});
```

Is there a way I can find the index of a person like this?

```
People.IndexOf(new object[] {"Sam", 18});
```

I've tried doing it like it is above, but it returns `-1`.

---

Solved this in my own crappy way by creating an extension method which takes a string parameter and loops through the list until it matches with one, then returns that index.

```
public static int OIndexOf(this List<object[]> List, string Check)
{
    for (int I = 0; I < List.Count; I++)
    {
        if ((string)List[I][0] == Check)
            return I;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Think about what the word `new` means.

Comment: I think you could definitely be using the object from object-oriented to help you solve this problem here. Why are you using an array of objects to describe an entity for which you have a structured pattern? Make a class with each field and override equals.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my oversight, although my original point is asking for a similar alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you're going to need a concrete type to make this work, like a `Person` object or an `int` value.

The reason this is the case is because your type must implement an `.Equals()` method.  It won't work with `object` objects, because the .Equals method for `object` compares *references,* not *values,* and your comparison will always return `false` unless you have the original `object` (not the case in your code, where you're creating a `new` object for comparison.

From the [documentation for the IndexOf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-5.0):

> This method searches all the elements of a one-dimensional array for
> value. To determine whether value exists in array, the method performs
> an equality comparison by calling each element's Equals method until
> it finds a match. This means that if the element overrides the
> Object.Equals(Object) method, that override is called.

Therefore, you need a `Person` object with an `Equals()` override.  To wit:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Person other)
    {
        return Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }
}
```

If you want to compare an array of people, you need another type that encapsulates your Person array, and an Equals() method to check equality of every person in the array with every person in the other array.

Comment: It seems to me that this answer completely misses the point of the question. First, a `List<object>` would work fine _as long as the actual runtime type of the object overrides `Equals()`_. No concrete, non-`object` type is needed. Second, the OP's example is a `List<object[]>`, which means the real problem here is that arrays don't implement value-equality, so one would have to implement a custom `IndexOf()` (e.g. extension) method that knows how to compare arrays for value-equality.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: Yeah, so? The first part of your answer is just plain wrong. Or at the very least, you've failed to express yourself precisely enough to convey the information that actually needs to be conveyed. (Yes, array's don't override `Equals()`, but your post doesn't seem to be discussing that, or discussing overrides at all)

Comment: You said it yourself; you can use object, but the runtime type needs to be something that implements `Equals()` which means you still need a concrete type, unless you can think of a way to implement Equals() in a class without actually creating the class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll try putting in what you've explained to me. I'll get back to you as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a reference to the actual array you wanted to look for then `IndexOf` would work in the way you want. But you are creating a new array, so it won't work.

The simplest way to do what you want is to use `FindIndex`:

```cs
People.FindIndex(p => p[0] == "Sam" && p[1] == 18)
```

To compare to the whole of an array in a variable at the same indices, use LINQ's `SequenceEqual`

```cs
var arr = new object[] {"Sam", 18};
People.FindIndex(p => arr.SequenceEqual(p));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it, you have to do it yourself.

Example: Create a new function:

```
int NewIndexOf(people, item)
{
    int index = 0;
    if(people.length) < 2
        return -1;

    foreach(var p in people)
    {
        p[0].Equals("Sam") && p[1].Equals(18)
        return index;
        ++index;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't something missing near "`p[0].Equals("Sam")`"? Like an `if`? Did you test/compile this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `IndexOf` uses the default equality comparer for a given type - `Object`, which is in your case
comparers *references*. You have *two* `new` - *two* different referencies, which in turn means
that both instances are considered unequal. To solve the problem you can:

Implement your own class:

```
 public class Person : IEquatable<Person> {
   public Person(string name, int age) {
     if (null == name)
       throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
     if (age < 0)
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(age));

     Name = name;
     Age = age;
   }

   public String Name {get;}

   public int Age {get;}

   public bool Equals(Person other) =>
     other != null && other.Name == Name && other.Age == Age;

   public override bool Equals(Object o) => Equals(o as Person);

   public override int GetHashCode() => Name.GetHashCode() ^ Age;
 }
```

Then you can put

```
 List<Person> People = new List<Person>();

 People.Add(new Person("Sam", 18));

 // Now .NET knows how to compare Person instances
 int index = People.IndexOf(new Person("Sam", 18));
```

Another approach (not a good practice, though) is to find `index` manually, with a help of [LINQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query):

```
 List<object[]> People = new List<object[]>();

 ...

 var index = People
    .Select((v, i) => new { v, i })
    .FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.v.SequenceEqual(new object[] { "Sam", 18 }))
   ?.i ?? -1;
```